# joining 2 tables with conditions and different number of rows

Tags: r

I want to join two `data.table`s with different number of rows

```
Table 1= 18000 rows
Table 2= 3000 rows
```

For matching the two tables , there are different conditions
First condition: ID of table 2 should be similar to ID of table 1
Second condition : date of table 2 should be equal or superior of start date of table 1 and inferior to the end date of table 1
I tried a code like this and it did not work

```
match<-Table1[Table2, on = c("ID.currency==ID.currency",  "start date<=date table2","end date>date table2")]
```

Thank you very much for your help

Table 1:
structure(list(ID.currency.startdate.open.high.low.close.volume.enddate.number.of.trades = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("EURCHF,01/11/2017 01:00,1.1639,1.1656,1.1619,1.162,5500,01/11/2017 01:59,1555", 
"EURCHF,01/11/2017 02:00,1.1651,1.1666,1.1633,1.164,6000,01/11/2017 02:59,1900", 
"EURCHF,01/11/2017 03:00,1.1645,1.1662,1.1641,1.1657,6100,01/11/2017 03:59,3000", 
"EURUSD,01/11/2017 00:00,1.1619,1.1646,1.1659,1.1607,5000,01/11/2017 00:59,1500", 
"EURUSD,01/11/2017 04:00,1.1619,1.1646,1.1659,1.1607,7000,01/11/2017 04:59,3500"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Table2:
structure(list(user.name.ID.currency.date.score = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("Alpha,EURCHF,31/11/2017  00:57:00,2.98", 
"Alpha,EURUSD,01/11/2017 00:44,2.5", "Beta,EURCHF,31/11/2017  00:57:00,1.78", 
"Beta,EURUSD,01/11/2017 04:12,3.23", "Beta,EURUSD,31/12/2018 00:17,0.678"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Output:

structure(list(ID.currency.startdate.open.high.low.close.volume.enddate.number.of.trades.user.name.ID.currency.date.score = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("EURCHF,01/11/2017 01:00,1.1639,1.1656,1.1619,1.162,5500,01/11/2017 01:59,1555,NA,NA,NA,NA", 
"EURCHF,01/11/2017 02:00,1.1651,1.1666,1.1633,1.164,6000,01/11/2017 02:59,1900,NA,NA,NA,NA", 
"EURCHF,01/11/2017 03:00,1.1645,1.1662,1.1641,1.1657,6100,01/11/2017 03:59,3000,NA,NA,NA,NA", 
"EURUSD,01/11/2017 00:00,1.1619,1.1646,1.1659,1.1607,5000,01/11/2017 00:59,1500,Alpha,EURUSD,01/11/2017 00:44,2.5", 
"EURUSD,01/11/2017 04:00,1.1619,1.1646,1.1659,1.1607,7000,01/11/2017 04:59,3500,Beta,EURUSD,01/11/2017 04:12,3.23"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: It showed me Error in `[.data.frame`(table1, table2,on= c("ID.currency==ID.currency",  
  :unused argument on = c("ID.currency==ID.currency", "start date<=date table2","end date>date table2"))

Comment: can you please include a sample of each of your datasets? also double check that `on` is an actual argument in what you're trying to do

Comment: you find above a sample of my datasets , thank you

Comment: You could first merge those two tables with the ID then filter out the rows not meeting second condition.

Comment: please do not post images of data!! include copy/pasteable data by using `dput(head(data))` and including the output in your question

Comment: @RAB I added the datasets and the output. Thank you

Comment: I tried everything but i still get the error [.data.frame , unused argument

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details of my sessionInfo
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer. Include it in the question as an "Edit".